# Highcharts-serverside-export not rendering graph with Rhino 1.7R3

Tags: highcharts, server-side, rhino

I need to export graph using Highcharts-serverside-export with Rhino/Batik (One2team) to use in my PDF. The problem

1. I am able to get a nice SVG with the graph when used HighChart with Rhino-1.7R2.
2. When used HighChart with Rhino-1.7R3 I got SVG without a graph.

I need to use Rhino1.7-R3 because in my project we are using WRO4J (WRO4J has dependency with Rhino-1.7R3). If I m using Rhino-1.7R2 it is solving my problem but creating a more bigger problem by breaking the whole UI of my application.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Highcharts-serverside-export deployed as a part of your web app? 
Since it requires an older version of rhino, you have the following options:

1. Use older version of wro4j (<=1.4.5) which is compatible with rhino-1.7.R2
2. Deploy highchart in a different web app. This way it could use the rhino-1.7.R2 and doesn't conflict with the web app using wro4j which uses rhino-1.7.R3.

Comment: 1st Options did not worked. 2nd option will not work because i need a Image stream from the highchart to use in my PDF export. One more it is not allow by for my project.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the 1st option didn't work? Also, if you don't really use any processor requiring rhino, you can exclude the rhino dependency... (this would be option 3)